# Unable to return length of array created in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created an array which contains query string values from url

```
var vars = [], hash;
var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');

for (var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
     hash = hashes[i].split('=');
     vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
}
```

If I want to iterate it, won't happens anything:

```
$.each(query_array, function(k, v) {
   console.log(v);
});
```

Then I wrote

```
console.log(query_array.length);
```

But my array looks like in Chrome console:

`[keyword: "mercedes", redirectTo: "test.aspx", remove: function]`

The length returns 0. Why ?

How could I iterate through this kind of array ?

Comment: I ran your function, and I think the arrays are actually different of what you wrote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var vars = []` should be changed to `var vars = {}` as your creating Object. `[]` represents Array.

Then, `$.each` will work.

Also you can get query string using location.search instead of location.href. Please check the updated code below

```
var vars = {}, hash;
var hashes = window.location.search.substring(1).split('&');

for (var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
     hash = hashes[i].split('=');
     vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you make `vars` an `object`, not an `array` it will work fine for you:

```
var vars = {}, hash;
var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');

for (var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
     hash = hashes[i].split('=');
     vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
}

console.log(vars) //Object {keyword: "mercedes", redirectTo: "test.aspx", remove: function}
```

You cannot access an array's element by an index, that is not a number. In your case - the index is not a number.

Answer (score 1):

`vars` is not an array. In javascript arrays must always have integer indexes. In your case you using strings as indexes:

```
vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
```

So don't create an array, just create an object:

```
var vars = {}, hash;
```

and you will be able to iterate over the properties of this object:

```
$.each(vars, function(k, v) {
    console.log(k + ': ' + v);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I'll give a detailed explanation for this.

Every object in JavaScript can act like a Map(Dictionary). Something like this.

```
var a = new Object();
a["foo"] = 10;
a["bar"] = 20;
```

...

Even an `Array` (`[]`) is an object. So it will respect the same behavior. Like this...

```
var arr = [];
arr["foo"] = 10;
arr["bar"] = 20;
```

But this does not mean you are using the Array as it is supposed to be used. Even though you have added properties to your Array, you have NOT added any element to the array and because of that the length count is 0. So maybe you should keep the count as a separate key/value pair.

Hope you understood.